# How can i implement letters in a multidimensional array at a random position in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I've been programming for two hours for the "Battleship game" in c.

After i finished it, it got pretty quickly boring.

So my question is, can i implement letters in a multidimensional array at a random position in c?

My code looks like this:

```
char matrix[9][9]={ 
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','S','S','S'},
{'.','S','S','S','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','S','S','S','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','S','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'S','.','.','S','.','.','.','S','.'},
{'S','.','.','S','.','.','.','S','.'},
{'S','.','.','.','.','.','.','S','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','S','.','S','.'},
```

Is there a solution to do this?

Comment: yes, look up sparse array

Comment: Pick the type of ship - and its length. Pick where to place one end - and its direction. See if every cell is empty - if so place the ship.

Comment: With a contiguous array (such as this), you only need to generate a random number from `[0, 81)` (9*9), such that you can get a random position via `matrix + (rand * sizeof(char))`